# Track user activity in Shiny app

Tags: r, google-analytics, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I have a shiny dashboard app which can be accessed by entering an email address in a text box. On successfully logging in I provide 3 tabs and a notification menu for each user. This pretty much works well. I want to however track the activity of users on my app.

I know by using session$clientData, I can log users IP address, but I want to be able to track which user visits which tabs and if at all they click on any of the notifications. Is there anyway I can do this for every session that is created? I know Google analytics [(here)](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/google-analytics.html) is a solution, but is there no other way? Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is an automated way but I create reactive values per user to take record of their activities. you need to do this server side, so when a button is clicked just have the server modify that reactive variable. on exit, save everything

Comment: @OganM, I did think of this, but I need to store these values for every session and am not sure if it'll work the way you mentioned. Appreciate the help!

Comment: yes for every session you need to create the reactive values. As far as I know it does work. I use rdrop2 package as described in @daattali's blog post to create a file per user fingerprint (ip + browser fingerpint. ip isn't always available if you are running it on shinyapps.io. fingerprint can be acquired as decribed in: https://gist.github.com/srvanderplas/6049567). Alternatively you can modify files as users do their thing but that will sneak read write operations in between user's actions which can slow down users depending on your logging frequency.

Comment: @OganM is correct, that should work

Comment: Great help @OganM! Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to log the user's IP address except with client-side Javascript (at this time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use Google Analytics, you could just write out the information you want to a file or to a 3rd party database/file storage system. [This article on persistent storage in shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html) could give you some ideas on how to do that

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: using the link you shared, I know I can store the values from the text box that I have, but is there a way I can track if the user selected any of the tabs?

Comment: You'd just have to write your own code to keep track of  whether a tab is clicked on. For example, you could have a reactive variable that keeps track of tabs clicked, and when a tab is clicked it changes the variable. (If you add an "id" attribute to your `tabsetPanel` then you can find out when a tab is clicked with `input$id`)

Comment: I actually used the onclick option available in the shinjs package you wrote. It works well for me but there is still some difficulty I have which I'll ask in another question. Thanks though!